# utl_tcp fetch exact length of response

Tags: oracle-19c, tcpip

I am using utl_tcp to connect to an external service and return some data.  All is fine until I get to this line:

```
utl_tcp.get_text(c, 100)
```

The issue with this is the call waits for the timeout I have specified in the connection for  all 100 bytes to be returned.  Usually, there are far less than 100 bytes, but that means my call sits there for, say, 30 seconds before completing the procedure.

In C# I can get the response length, so I can call for the exact number of characters I need, thus overcoming the timeout issue.  However, I can't use C# for this particular requirement, so I am hoping that someone has come across this issue and can give me a pointer.